# Problem with getting list of HCI devices from driver in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, driver, hci

I have to work with HCI device of Android, so I try to implement a simple code for get the number of bluetooth device:

```
...
struct hci_dev_req *dr;

int sk = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, BTPROTO_HCI);
if (sk < 0)
{
    res = "invalid socket";
    goto end;
}

struct hci_dev_list_req *dl = malloc(HCI_MAX_DEV * sizeof(*dr) + sizeof(*dl));
if (!dl)
{
    res = "not enough memory";
    goto end;
}

memset(dl, 0, HCI_MAX_DEV * sizeof(*dr) + sizeof(*dl));

dl->dev_num = HCI_MAX_DEV;
dr = dl->dev_req;

if (ioctl(sk, HCIGETDEVLIST, (void *) dl) < 0)
{
    res = "unable to get device list";
    goto end;
}

if(dl->dev_num == 0)
{
    res = "device list is empty";
    goto end;
}
...
```

So everytime I got the message "device list is empty". Why can it be?
Only permissions I have in program manifest them: BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN. And I run the application as simple user and not as root.

Tnx.

Comment: I assume you are using JNI to call this code.  Is it a requirement to use C++ and not the Java Android API?

Comment: Yes, I'm using JNI, cause it is the only way to use hci device directly ( ioctl(int, int, ...) funciton ). Android API is not implement hci (low level) protocol, but only rfcomm (high level) and it not enough for what I want to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I find the reason: device won't answer to simple user (and doesn't matter what permissions did you ask in program manifest). You can directly speak to device only if you are root (or from kernel mode). That means you cannot use devices directly from general applications. Very sad :(