# How to find out # devices w. bluez

Tags: c, bluez

I tried..

```
int a = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_CLOEXEC, BTPROTO_HCI);
if (a < 0)
{
  return 1;
}

hci_dev_list_req* b;

b = (hci_dev_list_req*)malloc(sizeof (hci_dev_list_req) + HCI_MAX_DEV * sizeof(hci_dev_req));
memset(b, 0, sizeof(hci_dev_list_req) + HCI_MAX_DEV * sizeof(hci_dev_req));

b->dev_num = HCI_MAX_DEV;

int c = ioctl(a, HCIGETDEVLIST, (void*)b);

free(b);
close(a);

if(c < 0)
{
  return 1;
}

printf("b->dev_num %hu\n", b->dev_num);
```

However.. here for me `b->dev_num 0` would be printed.
The code above is pretty much copy paste from hci_for_each_dev (see https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L828).

What is confusing is that hci_get_route then (after this code is run) doesn't return -1, which looking at [bluez source](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L900) makes no sense because..

**1.** hci_get_route ALWAYS assigns the result of hci_for_each_dev to the return value
**2.** hci_for_each_dev only ever not returns -1 if "dev_num" > 0

PROOF of **1.** ([source](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L900))..

```
int hci_get_route(bdaddr_t *bdaddr)
{
    int dev_id;

    dev_id = hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, __other_bdaddr,
                (long) (bdaddr ? bdaddr : BDADDR_ANY));
    if (dev_id < 0)
        dev_id = hci_for_each_dev(HCI_UP, __same_bdaddr,
                (long) (bdaddr ? bdaddr : BDADDR_ANY));

    return dev_id;
}
```

PROOF of **2.** ([source](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L856))..

```
    for (i = 0; i < dl->dev_num; i++, dr++) {
        if (hci_test_bit(flag, &dr->dev_opt))
            if (!func || func(sk, dr->dev_id, arg)) {
                dev_id = dr->dev_id;
                break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might be the answer..

> You can directly speak to device only if you are root (or from kernel mode).

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421210/problem-with-getting-list-of-hci-devices-from-driver-in-android)